# Is this Indian snake venomous?

Tags: species-identification, snake

I found this snake near a small garden.

Location: India (Hyderabad, south India)

Temperature: 38 <sup>o</sup>C

Humidity: 28%

Time: 2 hours past noon (2PM).

Similar snake was found in drainage of our locality.

[image]